# Ajax multiple data POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form with several inputs. I need to get the values of these inputs and send them to different webservices so the client could get an offer from different companies about his life insurance.I have always done it this way:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/url/webservice1.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data:{
           customer_name : $("#customer_name").val(),
           customer_id : $("#customer_id ").val(),
           customer_address : $("#customer_address ").val(),
           customer_age : $("#customer_age ").val()
       }
```

But since I am trying to send this data to webservice2.php, webservice3.php etc. ... it doesn't work for me . 
Can someone give me a better approach or tell me how to modify mine so the data could be passed to all webservices at once.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you check in the inspector of browser if you see in the area networks the requests sent by ajax?

Comment: yes the request is sent :) the question is how to send the data to several php files....

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var urls = ["/url/webservice1.php", "/url/webservice2.php", "/url/webservice3.php"];
$.each(urls, function(index, value) {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: value,
           dataType: "json",
           data:{
               customer_name : $("#customer_name").val(),
               customer_id : $("#customer_id ").val(),
               customer_address : $("#customer_address ").val(),
               customer_age : $("#customer_age ").val()
           },
           success: function(data){
               // you put here your code for all urls                  

               // or you put a personalized code for each url
               switch(value) {
               case "/url/webservice1.php":
                   //code of /url/webservice1.php
                   break;
               case "/url/webservice2.php":
               //code of /url/webservice2.php
                   break;
               case "/url/webservice3.php":
                   //code of /url/webservice3.php
                   break;
               }
           });
  });
```

Comment: this is good idea, but how can get response from each webservice?

Comment: thanks mate. The only doubt I have is it will wait for webservice1.php to respond and will continue.

Comment: I didn't understand your doubt. Do you want  webservice1.php to finish before webservice2.php and so on?